# Connection to node -1 (localhost) could not be established. Broker may not be available

Tags: java, spring-kafka

I am trying to run a basic Spring-Kafka application. I will show my codebase and the error I am getting.

**Consumer.java**

```
@Component
public class Consumer {

@KafkaListener(topics="appTopic",groupId="group1")
public void listenMessage(String message) {
    System.out.println(message);
} }
```

**ConsumerConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
public class ConsumerConfiguration {

@Value(value="${kafka.server}")
private String serverAddress;

@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(
      ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, 
      serverAddress);
    props.put(
      ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, 
      "group1");
    props.put(
      ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, 
      StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(
      ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, 
      StringDeserializer.class);
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
}

@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> 
  kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {

    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory =
      new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    return factory;
}}
```

**DemoApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
}


@Bean
public ApplicationRunner runner(Publisher p) {
    return args -> {
        p.sendMessage("Hello");
    };
}}
```

**KafkaConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfig {

@Value(value="${kafka.server}")
private String serverAddress;

@Bean
public KafkaAdmin kafkaAdmin() {
    Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<>();
    configs.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, serverAddress);
    return new KafkaAdmin(configs);
}

@Bean
public NewTopic topic() {
    return new NewTopic("appTopic", 10, (short) 2);
}
```

**ProducerConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
public class ProducerConfiguration {
    
@Value(value="${kafka.server}")
private String serverAddress;

@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<>();
    configs.put(
      ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, 
      serverAddress);
    configs.put(
      ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, 
      StringSerializer.class);
    configs.put(
      ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, 
      StringSerializer.class);
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configs);
}

@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
}
```

**Publisher.java**

```
@Component
public class Publisher {

@Autowired
KafkaTemplate<String, String> template;

public void sendMessage(String message) {
    
    //we can check the callback 
    template.send("appTopic", message);
    
}}
```

**application.properties**

```
kafka.server=localhost:9092
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.14.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
       <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
       <version>2.14.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Stacktrace :

```
2023-02-13T17:41:45.870+03:00  INFO 7768 --- [           main] 
o.a.k.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig    : AdminClientConfig values: 
bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
client.id = 
connections.max.idle.ms = 300000
default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
metric.reporters = []
metrics.num.samples = 2
metrics.recording.level = INFO
metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
request.timeout.ms = 30000
retries = 2147483647
retry.backoff.ms = 100
sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
sasl.jaas.config = null
sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
sasl.login.class = null
sasl.login.connect.timeout.ms = null
sasl.login.read.timeout.ms = null
sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
sasl.login.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
sasl.login.retry.backoff.ms = 100
sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
sasl.oauthbearer.clock.skew.seconds = 30
sasl.oauthbearer.expected.audience = null
sasl.oauthbearer.expected.issuer = null
sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.refresh.ms = 3600000
sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.ms = 100
sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.url = null
sasl.oauthbearer.scope.claim.name = scope
sasl.oauthbearer.sub.claim.name = sub
sasl.oauthbearer.token.endpoint.url = null
security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
security.providers = null
send.buffer.bytes = 131072
socket.connection.setup.timeout.max.ms = 30000
socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms = 10000
ssl.cipher.suites = null
ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
ssl.engine.factory.class = null
ssl.key.password = null
ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
ssl.keystore.key = null
ssl.keystore.location = null
ssl.keystore.password = null
ssl.keystore.type = JKS
ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3
ssl.provider = null
ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
ssl.truststore.certificates = null
ssl.truststore.location = null
ssl.truststore.password = null
ssl.truststore.type = JKS

2023-02-13T17:41:46.026+03:00  INFO 7768 --- [           main] 
 o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version: 3.3.2
 2023-02-13T17:41:46.026+03:00  INFO 7768 --- [           main] 
 o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId: b66af662e61082cb
 2023-02-13T17:41:46.026+03:00  INFO 7768 --- [           main] 
 o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka startTimeMs: 1676299306025
 2023-02-13T17:41:46.035+03:00  INFO 7768 --- [| adminclient-1] 
 org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node -1 
 disconnected.
 2023-02-13T17:41:46.036+03:00  WARN 7768 --- [| adminclient-1] 
 org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] 
  Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may 
 not be available.
 **2023-02-13T17:41:46.158+03:00  INFO 7768 --- [| adminclient-1] 
 org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node -1 
disconnected.** ( This is repeated log part like 30 times )
    org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: fetchMetadata

2023-02-13T17:42:16.059+03:00  INFO 7768 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node -1 disconnected.
2023-02-13T17:42:16.059+03:00  WARN 7768 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2023-02-13T17:42:16.040+03:00 ERROR 7768 --- [           main] o.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaAdmin  : Could not configure topics

java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.timedGet(CompletableFuture.java:1960) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:2095) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:180) ~[kafka-clients-3.3.2.jar:na]
at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaAdmin.initialize(KafkaAdmin.java:214) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaAdmin.afterSingletonsInstantiated(KafkaAdmin.java:183) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:972) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:915) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute ApplicationRunner
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:761) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:748) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Send failed
at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.doSend(KafkaTemplate.java:742) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.observeSend(KafkaTemplate.java:702) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.send(KafkaTemplate.java:486) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
at com.example.demo.Publisher.sendMessage(Publisher.java:16) ~[classes/:na]
at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.lambda$0(DemoApplication.java:19) ~[classes/:na]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic appTopic not present in metadata after 60000 ms.
```

It seems to me it should work and I check similar topics on stackoverflow but they generally use zookeeper and I am not.Do you have any suggestions ?
Thanks in advance for any comments and answers.

Answer (score -1):

To use Kafka without Zookeeper you need to setup KRaft, have you done this? Are you sure your Kafka instance is running properly?

Comment: I did the setup with kraft. I am running server,producer and consumer from WSL commandline but still no luck. I am getting "  Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established Broker may not be available. "